# Splitting a string by comma that is preceded by a specific word

Tags: java, regex, split

I want to split a query by comma only if it is preceded by `AS`.

A small part of My Query:

```
DATE_TRUNC('month', timestamp) AS month_begin_dt
        ,   FIRST_VALUE(monitorsessionid) OVER(PARTITION BY openpsid,DATE_TRUNC('month', timestamp) ORDER BY timestamp DESC) AS monitorsessionid
        ,   FIRST_VALUE(vrr) OVER(PARTITION BY openpsid,DATE_TRUNC('month', timestamp) ORDER BY timestamp DESC) AS vrr
```

I tried to split the query in java using the split() method with the following regular expression.

```
String[] queryArray = internalQuery.split(",(?![^\\(]*\\))");
```

I want my split array to have elements as:

```
[0] = DATE_TRUNC('month', timestamp) AS month_begin_dt

[1] = FIRST_VALUE(monitorsessionid) OVER(PARTITION BY openpsid,DATE_TRUNC('month', timestamp) ORDER BY timestamp DESC) AS monitorsessionid

[2] = FIRST_VALUE(vrr) OVER(PARTITION BY openpsid,DATE_TRUNC('month', timestamp) ORDER BY timestamp DESC) AS vrr
```

**The output I am getting in the queryArray is:**

```
[0] = DATE_TRUNC('month', timestamp) AS month_begin_dt

[1] = FIRST_VALUE(monitorsessionid) OVER(PARTITION BY openpsid

[2] = DATE_TRUNC('month', timestamp) ORDER BY timestamp DESC) AS monitorsessionid

[3] = FIRST_VALUE(vrr) OVER(PARTITION BY openpsid

[4] = DATE_TRUNC('month', timestamp) ORDER BY timestamp DESC) AS vrr
```

**The Desired Output in the queryArray**

```
[0] = DATE_TRUNC('month', timestamp) AS month_begin_dt

[1] = FIRST_VALUE(monitorsessionid) OVER(PARTITION BY
openpsid,DATE_TRUNC('month', timestamp) ORDER BY timestamp DESC) AS monitorsessionid

[2] = FIRST_VALUE(vrr) OVER(PARTITION BY openpsid,DATE_TRUNC('month', timestamp) ORDER BY timestamp DESC) AS vrr
```

Comment: can you provide a minimal reproducable example? The way the question is now, it is pretty hard to figure out what exactly problem you are having

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Java you can use this regex for splitting:

```bash
(?<=\s{1,99}[aA][sS]\s{1,99}\w{1,99})\s*,\s*
```

We are using finite range quantifiers `{1,99}` instead of just `+` here because Java regex engine doesn't allow dynamic length look behind assertions.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/WpFIF3/2)

**Java Code:**

```bash
String[] queryArray = internalQuery.split(
   "(?<=\\s{1,99}[aA][aS]\\s{1,99}\\w{1,99})\\s*,\\s*");
```

**RegEx Breakdown:**

- `(?<=\s{1,99}[aA][sS]\s{1,99}\w{1,99})`: Lookbehind assertion that makes sure that we have word `AS` (ignore case) surrounded with 1 to 99 whitespaces on either side followed by a 1+ (upto 99) word characters as alias name
- `\s*,\s*`: Match a comma surrounded with 0 or more whitespaces on either side

Comment: You can perhaps use `{1,}`?

Comment: Unfortunately no, that will make it non-fixed width.

Comment: It does work if the query contains AS

Comment: @anubhava I am still able to use `\\w{1,}` or even `\\w+` in Java (17.0.1), though it is said repetition is not allowed inside look-behind. Why?

Comment: @AnimeshPanigrahi: I have modified answer to handle `AS` or `as` or `As` or `aS`.

Comment: @NikolasCharalambidis: Java regex engine (and most of the regex engines) don't allow repetitions in lookbehind because that makes lookbehind condition of dynamic length.

Comment: @anubhava, I have another question. let's say my query is :
`SELECT DISTINCT  openpsid ,   
FIRST_VALUE(monitorsessionid) OVER(PARTITION BY openpsid,DATE_TRUNC('month', timestamp) ORDER BY timestamp DESC) AS monitorsessionid`


What should be my regEx in order to have the following output:

[0] = SELECT DISTINCT openpsid

[1] =  FIRST_VALUE(monitorsessionid) OVER(PARTITION BY openpsid,DATE_TRUNC('month', timestamp) ORDER BY timestamp DESC) AS monitorsessionid

How to handle the cases where there is no ALIASING i.e AS keyword? I want to store all the statements before a column name.

Comment: Complex query parsing with pure regex is not easy. I suggest you post a new question with this new question so that we understand it better and suggest your best approach.